# What does 'ed' mean?

Tags: medical

I natively speak Swedish and have been studying medicine over here, but got offered to learn from a British professor online. And when he went through all the different branches he kept referring to the ER as ED?
Does this stand for Emergency dorm or what does it stand for?

Comment: ED = Emergency Department.  So it is more than just one room, so it is not ER = Emergency Room.

Comment: ED is a relatively new term in British hospitals where they were usually called the A&E (Accident & Emergency) department.

Comment: "he kept referring to the ER as ED" - he correctly referred to the ED as the ED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ER and ED are the same thing when considered as a place to receive emergency medical care. Of course the Emergency Department at a hospital is likely to have a number of individual Emergency Rooms or Bays.

**emergency room**

> North American
> The **department** of a hospital that provides immediate treatment for
> acute illnesses and trauma. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/emergency_room)

**emergency department**

> North American
> A casualty department; = "emergency **room**"; abbreviated **ED**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/emergency_department)

My health insurance card lists "in-network member responsibilities" (fees) for:

> Primary...
> Specialist...
> Urgent Care...
> **ER**...

*Urgent Care* facilities are usually separate facilities, buildings, etc. often in several locations in a community. *Urgent* in this case means the patient thinks the problem requires immediate attention but is not serious  enough to require an ED/ER or hospital admission. However, someone might need to be transported from an Urgent Care facility to an ER/ED for treatment and/or admitted to a hospital.

> **Urgent Care Centers**
>
> An urgent care center is a walk-in clinic focused on the delivery of
> medical care for minor illnesses and injuries in an ambulatory medical
> facility outside of a traditional hospital-based or freestanding
> emergency department. Other names for similar types of facilities
> include, but are not limited to: after hours walk-in clinics, minute
> clinics, quick care clinics, minor emergency centers, and minor care
> clinics. [American College of Emergency Physicians](https://www.acep.org/patient-care/policy-statements/urgent-care-centers/)